# How to use multiple WITH statements and multiple INSERT statements in the same query

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I'm struggling to use `WITH` in combination with `INSERT`. I've *massively* simplified the queries for sake of example.

I know this can be written without `WITH`, but **if I want to use `WITH` *and* multiple `INSERT` what syntax should I use?**

```
WITH table_1_items AS (
  SELECT * FROM example_table_1
),
table_2_items AS (
  SELECT * FROM example_table_2
)

INSERT INTO other_table_1 FROM table_1_items;
INSERT INTO other_table_2 FROM table_2_items;
```

Results in error:

```
relation "table_2_items" does not exist
```

Comment: You can't reuse a WITH table later. Create views instead.

Comment: @jarlh can you post an example snippet?

Comment: `create view table_1_items AS SELECT * FROM example_table_1`.

Comment: The CTE is pretty much useless. You probably have simplified your example to a point where it doesn't really show the actual problem any more. As written, the CTE is not needed and you can simply write two INSERT statements that use the `SELECT`s from each CTE

Comment: @wilsonpage, you have so much simplified your example that it makes no sense to combine  both INSERT in the same statement in your case. Can you complexify a little bit your example so that to understand where is the interest of combining both INSERT in the same statement ?

Comment: @EdouardH. maybe I am missing the point a little. I thought `WITH` was just some nice syntactic sugar to avoid some hard to read deeply nested `SELECT`s? I'm writing a data migration script that will pull some rows out of two tables and write into a new table.

Comment: @wilsonpage : My point is that the solution proposed by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) could be split into two separated statement : `WITH table_1_items AS (...) INSERT INTO other_table_1 FROM table_1_items` on one side and `WITH table_2_items AS (...) INSERT INTO other_table_2 FROM table_2_items` on the other side. So there is no interest for merging both statements in one here.

Answer (score 1):

The INSERTs need to be part of the same CTE:

```
WITH table_1_items AS (
  SELECT * FROM example_table_1
),
table_2_items AS (
  SELECT * FROM example_table_2
), 
insert_table_1 as (
  INSERT INTO other_table_1 FROM table_1_items
)
INSERT INTO other_table_2 FROM table_2_items;
```

Comment: thanks! Will the `insert_table_1` section be run if not referenced elsewhere?